# Cannot resolve external dependency

Tags: gradle, kotlin

Hello I'am new in Android. I got stuck here and this error appears:

> Cannot resolve external dependency org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-
>   plugin:1.3.31 because no repositories are defined. Required by:
>       project :app

`build.gradle` module

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ahmadnaser.startapp"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "APP_ID", "\"ec5617b9-b9e4-4cbf-b7c1-91d8aea47bb2\""
            buildConfigField "String", "CLIENT_KEY", "\"185c55ba-b15f-4f1d-991f-95fdaf9a85b3\""
            buildConfigField "String", "SERVER_URL", "\"https://antest123.azurewebsites.net/parse\""
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:29.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:29.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:29.1.0'
    implementation 'com.parse:parse-android:1.15.7'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.31"
    }
}
```

`build.gradle` app

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://myrepourl/repo' }

    }
    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.0-alpha03'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.31"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://myrepourl/repo' }
        }


    }


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

what should I do to fix up this error?